# Why does it show me the "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'" error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export interface IFormSelect<
  T extends FieldValues,
  U extends IOption = IOption,
  V = any
  > {
  control: Control<T, any>;
  name: keyof T;
  defaultValue?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  options: U[];
  formatOptions?: (data: U, formatOptionLabelMeta: FormatOptionLabelMeta<U>) => ReactNode;
  setValue?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<V>>;
}
```

```
const FormSelect = <T extends IOption = IOption, U = any>({
                                                     control,
                                                     defaultValue,
                                                     name,
                                                     options,
                                                     placeholder,
                                                     formatOptions,
                                                     setValue
                                                   }: IFormSelect<IOrderForm, T, U>) => {
  return (
    <div className='w-96 z-[41]'>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        render={({ field: { value, onChange, ref } }) => (
          <Select
            ref={ref}
            options={options}
            value={options.filter(option => typeof value === 'string' && value.includes(option.value))}
            onChange={(val) => {
              onChange(val?.value);
              if (setValue && val?.value) setValue('hello');
            }}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            formatOptionLabel={formatOptions}
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the "if (setValue && val?.value) setValue('hello')" line it constantly throws me the error which i genuinely do not understand why. Cause i specified that setState could take any argument in the interface, tho it still says that there's an error.
What do i need to do to fix this and most important what is the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

The interface contains `setValue?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<V>>;`

In my code I have

```
setValue('hello')
```

but `hello` is a string while in the interface, the argument type is `Dispatch<SetStateAction<V>> | undefined`.

P.S. I'm a beginner, may be it's wrong :)